# Slim Application Error when connecting to db

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api, slim-3

I'm newbie on Restful API's. I'm trying to make my own following internet tutorials. For this API i'm using Slim PHP Framework.

I've create my db.php (config file):

```
<?php
class db{
    //Properties
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    private $dbname = 'Connect';
    //Connect
    //create MYSQL connect string
    public function connect(){
        $mysql_connect_str = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname";
        $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, POD::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbConnection;
    }
}
```

And then i've got my students.php (Where i'm trying to fetch the data to):

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

$app = new \Slim\App;

//Get All Students 

$app->get('/api/students', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student";

        try{
            $db = new db();
            // connect 
            $db = $db->connect();

            $stmt = $db->query($sql);
            $students = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;
            echo json_encode($students);


        } catch(PDOException $e){
            //e for errors exception handling
             echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
        }

});
```

My index.php:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'src/config/db.php'; 

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
    return $response;
});

//Customer Routes
require 'src/routes/students.php';

$app->run();
```

When im loading my students.php file(http://localhost:8080/rest/index.php/api/students) there is this Error shown:

Slim Application Error
A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

When I run terminal and use this command:
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
It connects to the db. So the properties should be right. 
I still don't know where is the Problem. 
Thank you to everyone for reading and answering!

Edit: Im using xampp for the db

Second Edit: I removed a aline of the db.php file

```
<?php
class db{
    //Properties
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    private $dbname = 'Connect';
    //Connect
    //create MYSQL connect string
    public function connect(){
        $mysql_connect_str = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname";
        $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        //$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, POD::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbConnection;
    }
}
```

I removed this line and now its showing the table I've selected. But why do I have to remove this line? I followed a tutorial and there is this line shown.

Comment: Check your server error logs, there should be some more information in there about what went wrong.

Comment: where can I find my error log?